# Python Thread Update Arg

Tags: python, multithreading

Searched for this but could not find anything, so I suspect it can't be done.

I need to update arguments to a running thread:

```
def doLeds(*leds):
    onoff = 0
    while 1:
        onoff=not onoff
        for led in leds:
            wpi.digitalWrite(led,onoff)
            time.sleep(0.025)


def thread():
    from threading import Thread
    leds = Thread(target=doLeds, args=([17,22,10,9,11]))
    leds.start()
    print(leds)
    time.sleep(5)
    leds['args']=[10,9,11]
```

Is it possible to update thread vars / arguments after the thread has been started ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. It's easy if you subclass `Thread`. Then, you can directly assign to its attributes.

```
class LedThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, args):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.args = args
    def run(self):
        self.doLeds()
    def doLeds(self):
        onoff = 0
        while 1:
            onoff=not onoff
            for led in self.args:
                wpi.digitalWrite(led,onoff)
                time.sleep(0.025)

t = LedThread([17,22,10,9,11])
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
t.args = [10,9,11]
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thanks shx2 & @Alex Brault, in the end I used a global variable as I used one thread for each led and this seemed the easiest way to update their status.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the basic threads with a callable, you can't change the arguments. That's because after the thread starts, it passes the arguments to your target, then forgets about them.

What you can do instead is create a class that extends `threading.Thread`. Then, you can have a field with what you used to pass as an argument. For example:

```
from threading import Thread

class LedThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, leds):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.leds = leds

    def run(self):
        onoff = 0
        while 1:
            onoff=not onoff
            for led in leds:
                wpi.digitalWrite(led,onoff)
                time.sleep(0.025)

def thread():
    leds = LedThread([17,22,10,9,11])
    leds.start()
    print(leds)
    time.sleep(5)
    leds.leds=[10,9,11]
```